# Magento 2: How to optimize the execution of the CLI?

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line

I run the command `php bin/magento` many times a day, so I'd like to know if I can optimize the execution of this one?

For example:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve the **memory limit** and create an alias as well, like that:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"
```

Then run the command below in your root installation folder:

```
mage cache:flush
```